# How can I make a MasterDetailPage icon VoiceOver accessible?

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, accessibility, voiceover

My Xamarin.Forms app's main page consists of a MasterDetailPage that looks like the following:

```
<MasterDetailPage ...>
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <v:MasterMenuPage Title="Menu" Icon="icon_hamburger.png" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        ...
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

As I tried 'listening' to my app on iOS 10 with VoiceOver activated, I noticed that the voice reads the menu icon as `Icon Hamburger` instead of `Menu`.

How can I set an accessibility text to overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding an [Accessibility Effect](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/accessibility/)?

Comment: I've tried that, but with no success.

Comment: Could you add the Effect code to your post with an explanation of what happened

Comment: Submitted my last comment too early ... I also upgraded to the latest Xamarin.Forms prerelease that comes with AutomationProperties support. No success either. What happened was ... nothing. VoiceOver still read the 'Icon Hamburger' icon property. I'll update my question soon, as I'm somewhat in a hurry right now.

Answer (score 1):

From looking through the Xamarin.Forms source code, and how it creates that navigation item.  I think the only way you are going to be able to set the accessibility label for that icon is by creating a custom renderer for NavigationPage.

This example, sets the label correctly for me.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(stackoverflowexample.iOS.CustomNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace stackoverflowexample.iOS
{
    public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var button = GetNavigationButton();

            if (button == null) return;

            button.AccessibilityLabel = GetMasterPageTitle();

        }

        UIBarButtonItem GetNavigationButton()
        {
            var nav = this.NativeView.Subviews.OfType<UINavigationBar>().FirstOrDefault();

            var navItem = nav.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LeftBarButtonItem != null);

            return navItem?.LeftBarButtonItem;
        }

        string GetMasterPageTitle()
        {
            var parentPages = ((Page)Element).GetParentPages();
            var masterDetail = parentPages.OfType<MasterDetailPage>().FirstOrDefault();

            return masterDetail?.Master?.Title;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
AutomationProperties.SetIsInAccessibleTree(yourElement, true);
AutomationProperties.SetName(yourElement, "textToBeSpoken");
```

source: https://blog.xamarin.com/accessbility-xamarin-forms/